# Swift não seta o texto no UITextFiled depois de atualizado para swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

Eu atualizei o `XCode` para `Swift 3` semana passada e ele converteu todo meu código para a versão do `Swift 3`. Depois disto eu estou tentando setar o texto dentro de um `UITextField` e não funciona. Eu já refiz todas as conexões do `UI` com o código mas não funciona.

Quando eu digito dentro do `UITextFiled` aparece, mas quando eu tento setar o texto programaticamente não aparece.

```
@IBOutlet weak var codigoTextField: UITextField!

codigoTextField.text = "3654"
```

Comment: Se puder, manda o código completo da sua ViewController que assim fica mais facil de entender o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes criando um novo projeto e tudo funciona normalmente. Parece que houve algum problema na hora da exportação para a versão 3 do `Swift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei o que aconteceu, mas eu reconstrui toda a interface do usuário e refiz todas as conexões. Agora funcionou.